# inserting incorrect date value into my

Tags: php, mysql

I have some date input boxes on an index.php page:

```
<label>Project Milestone Dates:</label>
<input type="date" name="date[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date1);?>">
<input type="date" name="date[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date2);?>">
<input type="date" name="date[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date3);?>">
<input type="date" name="date[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date4);?>">
<input type="date" name="date[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date5);?>">
<input type="date" name="date[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date6);?>">
<input type="date" name="date[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date7);?>">
<input type="date" name="date[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date8);?>">
<input type="date" name="date[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date8);?>">
<input type="date" name="date[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date10);?>">
```

when a submit button is pressed we go to another page that runs a couple of sql statements that inserts various data into a couple of tables.  Everything gets inserted to the first table, no issues.  I can also do a foreach() loop to display the values of the array, for testing.  The second insert is not working properly, the value for pId gets entered, however the array of dates are not being entered, show up as 0000-00-00 in the DB.  How can I get each date from the array to be inserted into datetable on its own line with the pId as the PK?

Here is my SQL for the insert:

```
$dates = $_GET['date'];

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO datetable (pId, date1)
    VALUES ('$pId', '$dates')";
    $conn->exec($sql2);
```

Comment: You cannot insert an array into a text field. You'll have to insert each date within a loop.

Comment: You're trying to insert the entire array of dates into a single date fiel din one go.... loop over the dates array, inserting one date at a time

Comment: @azryel6500 learn about [looping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php), I see 2 places which could do with loops

Comment: thanks, @Lawrence Cherone are you suggesting a loop for the Project Milestone Dates?

Comment: And learn to use parameterised statements.... the internet may be falling to pieces over Meltdown and Spectre, but that's no excuse for leaving yur own code open to SQL injections

Comment: @azryel6500 yeah, also variables like $date1 through to $date10 is 9 wasted variables, if you learn about arrays you could build or [compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) them into an array, then just loop over them. I generally aim to receive process and then pass back a well formed single array to my html/views, for some reason need it in json? then json encode it, and use a different view, instead of collecting them twice to output, my2cent.. happy coding

Comment: Thanks @ Lawrence Cherone for the direction, I will research that and get it to work, I did update the code to insert the dates and it is working mostly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to insert different rows use foreach loop,

```
        $dates = $_GET['date'];
        foreach($dates as $d){
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO datetable (pId, date1)
    VALUES ('$pId', '$d')";
    $conn->exec($sql2);
}
```

And if you want it into a same row,

```
     foreach($dates as $d){
        $dat.=$d.'whatever you want';
}
$d=rtrim($dat,'whatever you want');//it will remove unwanted (whatever you want)
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO datetable (pId, date1)
    VALUES ('$pId', '$d')";
    $conn->exec($sql2);
```